# Extending TemplateElement

Tags: dart, custom-element

I am *not* using Polymer and I am trying to extend the `TemplateElement`

```dart
class ItemTemplate extends TemplateElement{
  ItemTemplate.created():super.created();
}
```

and then register it

```dart
document.registerElement('item-template', ItemTemplate,extendsTag:'template');
```

but when i add the following to my html test page

```dart
  <template>
    template
  </template>

  <item-template>
    item-template
  </item-template>
```

in Chromium it outputs

```dart
item-template
```

which means the new element that extends `TemplateElement` is active and not acting as a template, any idea why?

**E:this is not a duplicate i said i am not using polymer and there is no polymer in the tags and its specifically about the behavior of the html5  `TemplateElement`**

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `not Polymer` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with extending elements without Polymer but I'm pretty sure you still need the `is="xx-yy" attribute like

```dart
<template is="item-template">
  item-template
</template is="item-template">
```

when you're extending a DOM element.

Maybe there are other measurements necessary to make it work but this should at least bring you a step closer (maybe an error message about what's still missing)

Comment: the is works but i was hoping that i can keep the use the item-template as tag name, seems its not possible

Comment: If this solves the problem I'm sure there is no way around. This is how custom-elements are defined (which is not Polymer, but Polymer also builds upon it).